# Allow all OG members to view/edit all content

Tags: organic-groups

I'm pretty new to OG and I'm testing a collaborative intranet site at this moment with Drupal7 and Organic Groups 7.x-2.3.

It is a simple app for a small group where all the members know each other and can be trusted. We're working on a [Degrowth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrowth) Workshop ([link to the workshop announcement](http://sevilladecrece.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/preparando-el-iii-encuentro-de-redes-e-iniciativas-decrecentistas-y-transicioneras/), in Spanish).

I've used OG to set the organizers in the different work areas (catering, activities, kids, lodging,...), have lists grouped by... groups (of course), and create a customized homepage for the members of the different groups. Everything ok until this point.

Now what I want is that **everyone (all registered users - there's NO access to anonymous) have access, can read, write, edit, comment, etc to any node, whether it be of their group or not**.

I'm fighting with the Field Settings, Permissions and roles but can't get to achieve it and there's always some hidden content to members of different groups. I've read quite a few solutions to similar issues but can't get a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organic groups controls (`Organic Groups Global Permissions`) are different from your site permission, roles etc. To allow authenticated users the required permission, configure the organic groups global permission:

Navigate to: Configuration -> Organic Groups Global Permissions (`drupal/admin/config/group/permissions`), here you will find the controls over who can view and edit nodes and fields on your group pages.

Few reference for the organic groups permission:
http://vimeo.com/32398425
http://vimeo.com/32398425
https://drupal.org/node/2014929
https://drupal.org/node/2014793